# Excel SUMIFS - Multiple Array

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, sumifs

I tried to include SUMIFS with single array and it works fine:

```
 =SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet3!H:H,Sheet3!G:G,"X",Sheet3!E:E,"SA",Sheet3!D:D,{"A","B","C"}))
```

When I try to include a second array as below it gives me only the first/last item  from {"X","Y","Z"}

```
 =SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet3!H:H,Sheet3!G:G,{"X","Y","Z"},Sheet3!E:E,"SA",Sheet3!D:D,{"A","B","C"}))
```

The only workaround I could figure out is by separating the formula in 3 chunks (each item in {"X","Y","Z"}).

Is there any other work around? Or two arrays in SUMIFS does not work properly?

Comment: You're right. I omitted it accidentally while editing. I've updated it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a row array for one of the lists and a column array for the other. Try this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet3!H:H, Sheet3!G:G, {"X","Y","Z"},
  Sheet3!E:E,"SA",Sheet3!D:D,{"A";"B";"C"}))
'                                ^   ^
```

The inner `SUMIFS` makes a cross-product of the two arrays; a matrix where each entry is the *"sumif"* matching both the corresponding row and column elements:

```
        X,A      Y,A    Z,A
        X,B      Y,B    Z,B
        X,C      Y,C    Z,C
```

Then the outer `SUM` adds up all the elements. As a result, you will have the sum where each field matches any element of it's criteria's array:

```
G:G is any of {"X","Y","Z"}      and      D:D is any of {"A";"B";"C"}
```

Of course the other, single condition `E:E="SA"` applies in all cases.

The two lists don't need to have the same cardinality.

This technique cannot be generalized to more than two lists. If you had a third criteria list, you need to proceed in a different way.